# ProcStartLine returns line number of empty line in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this below code which inserts "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler" and "ErrorHandler" label and its statements if it does not exist in a subroutine or a function.
I get line number of an empty line if the declaration line starts after a blank line like below.

**Subroutine with Blank line in front:**

```
Below empty line

Sub SubWithBothNotAvail()


d = k

End Sub
```

**Subroutine that inserts Error Handler:**

The workaround I've inserted starts after the comment `'*** Workaround starts ***`

```
Sub AddErrorHandlers(ModuleName)
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lineN As Long
Dim procName As String
Dim startOfProceedure As Long
Dim lengthOfProceedure As Long
Dim CodeModuleObj As CodeModule
Dim ReplaceJump, LineValue, PrevLineValue, LenLine, YesNo
Dim OnErrorGoToFound As Boolean, OnErrorGoToLabelFound As Boolean, AvailableLableNamesDic As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim ActualStartOfProcedureFound As Boolean
'ModuleName = "YourModuleName" 'Paste module name where lines' numbers should be added
On Error Resume Next
Set CodeModuleObj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName).CodeModule
If CodeModuleObj Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "Module Name " & ModuleName & " not exist"
  Exit Sub
End If

With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ModuleName).CodeModule
    i = 0
   Do While i <= .CountOfLines
    i = i + 1
       procName = .ProcOfLine(i, vbext_pk_Proc)
       If procName <> vbNullString Then
           startOfProceedure = .ProcStartLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)
           
           If i = startOfProceedure Then
           
            'It is because .ProcStartLine takes line number of a blank line. In this finding the blank line was above ProcLine

           '*** Workaround starts ***
           If InStr(1, .Lines(startOfProceedure, 1), procName & "(", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ActualStartOfProcedureFound = False: lengthOfProceedure = 0
            For j = startOfProceedure To .CountOfLines
             
             If InStr(1, .Lines(j, 1), procName & "(", vbTextCompare) Then
                 startOfProceedure = j
                 ActualStartOfProcedureFound = True
                 For k = startOfProceedure + 1 To .CountOfLines
                    If Left(.Lines(k, 1), 4) = "End " Then
                        lengthOfProceedure = k - startOfProceedure + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                 Next k
             End If
            Next j
           End If
           If Not lengthOfProceedure Then
            Exit Sub
           End If
                
           '*** Workaround Ends ***

                AvailableLableNamesDic.RemoveAll
                OnErrorGoToFound = False: OnErrorGoToLabelFound = False
               For j = 1 To lengthOfProceedure - 1
                   lineN = startOfProceedure + j

                   LineValue = .Lines(lineN, 1)
                   PrevLineValue = .Lines(lineN - 1, 1)
                   
                   If Left(Trim(LineValue), 13) = "On Error GoTo" Then
                    OnErrorGoToFound = True
                    ErrorHandlerLabelName = Replace(Split(Trim(LineValue), " ")(3), ":", "")
                   End If
                   If Right(LineValue, 1) = ":" Then
                    If InStr(1, LineValue, " ", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        AvailableLableNamesDic(Left(LineValue, Len(LineValue) - 1)) = j
                    End If
                   End If
                   If OnErrorGoToLabelFound Then
                    Exit For
                   ElseIf OnErrorGoToFound Then
                        If LineValue = ErrorHandlerLabelName & ":" Then
                            OnErrorGoToLabelFound = True
                        End If
                   End If
               Next j
               
                If OnErrorGoToLabelFound Then 'Both found. so can be skipped
                    Debug.Print procName & ":" & startOfProceedure & ":" & lengthOfProceedure & " Both found" & "," & .ProcOfLine(i, vbext_pk_Proc)
                ElseIf OnErrorGoToFound Then 'Need to insert the ErrorHandler
                    
                    k = startOfProceedure + lengthOfProceedure - 1
                    
                    .InsertLines k, ErrorHandlerLabelName & ":"
                    Debug.Print procName & ":" & startOfProceedure & ":" & lengthOfProceedure & " Need to insert the errorhandler. k value: " & k & "," & .ProcOfLine(k, vbext_pk_Proc)
                    .InsertLines k + 1, "If Err.Number <> 0 Then"
                    Debug.Print procName & ":" & startOfProceedure & ":" & lengthOfProceedure & " Need to insert the errorhandler. k value: " & k + 1 & "," & .ProcOfLine(k + 1, vbext_pk_Proc)
                    .InsertLines k + 2, "    PrintErrorLog ""Error Line: "" & Erl & "", Error Desc: "" & Err.Description & "", " & ModuleName & "." & procName
                    Debug.Print procName & ":" & startOfProceedure & ":" & lengthOfProceedure & " Need to insert the errorhandler. k value: " & k + 2 & "," & .ProcOfLine(k + 2, vbext_pk_Proc)
                    .InsertLines k + 3, "End If"
                    Debug.Print procName & ":" & startOfProceedure & ":" & lengthOfProceedure & " Need to insert the errorhandler. k value: " & k + 3 & "," & .ProcOfLine(k + 3, vbext_pk_Proc)
                ElseIf OnErrorGoToFound = False And OnErrorGoToLabelFound Then 'ErrorHandler label is there. Need to insert only 'On Error Go To ErrorHandler'
                    
                    .InsertLines startOfProceedure + 1, "On Error GoTo " & ErrorHandlerLabelName & ": d = " & """" & "Only on error" & """"
                    Debug.Print procName & ":" & startOfProceedure & ":" & lengthOfProceedure & " Need to insert only 'On Error Go To ErrorHandler'. startOfProceedure + 1: " & (startOfProceedure + 1) & "," & .ProcOfLine((startOfProceedure + 1), vbext_pk_Proc)
                Else 'Both should be inserted
                    
                    .InsertLines startOfProceedure + 1, "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler: d = " & """" & "Both" & """"
                    Debug.Print procName & ":" & startOfProceedure & ":" & lengthOfProceedure & " Both should be inserted'. startOfProceedure + 1: " & (startOfProceedure + 1) & "," & .ProcOfLine((startOfProceedure + 1), vbext_pk_Proc)
                    k = startOfProceedure + lengthOfProceedure - 1
                    .InsertLines k, ErrorHandlerLabelName & ":"
                    .InsertLines k + 1, "If Err.Number <> 0 Then"
                    .InsertLines k + 2, "    PrintErrorLog ""Error Line: "" & Erl & "", Error Desc: "" & Err.Description & "", " & ModuleName & "." & procName
                    .InsertLines k + 3, "End If"
               End If
           End If
       End If
   Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Is there any way to get correct start line by `ProcStartLine` without this ugly workaround in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
          startOfProceedure = .ProcStartLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)
```

use

```
          startOfProceedure = .ProcBodyLine(procName, vbext_pk_Proc)
```

this gives the declaration line number of the procedure.

Comment: But the next issue is created by ProcCountLines. It includes blank lines also.

Comment: @dhay I think that is correct, because it provides the absolute line number on the sheet.